# How can i get ExtentReport-cucumber report instance?

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, extentreports

I'm building new automation infrastructure using tesng, extent-report and cucumber integrated together.
using the following code.

```
@CucumberOptions(strict= false,
                    plugin = {"pretty" ,"html:test-output/cucumber",
                            "com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:",
                            "json:test-output/cucumber/cucumber.json", "pretty:test-output/cucumber/cucumber-pretty.txt",
                            "usage:test-output/cucumber/cucumber-usage.json", "junit:test-output/cucumber/cucumber-results.xml"
                            ,"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:test-output/cucumber/cucumber-extent-reports/report.html"}
                        // , glue = {"@User"}
                          , monochrome = true)
public abstract class SROTestInfra  extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{
    PageFactory pageFactory = new PageFactory();
    protected WebDriver driver;


}
```

I'm trying to report instance in order to add an Info messages, **but reprot access control is only for package** as shown in this open source code.

```
public class ExtentCucumberFormatter implements Reporter, Formatter {
  /* some code
     ****************
     ****************
 */

    private static void setExtentHtmlReport(ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReport) {
        htmlReporterThreadLocal.set(htmlReport);
    }

    static ExtentHtmlReporter getExtentHtmlReport() {
        return htmlReporterThreadLocal.get();
    }

    private static void setExtentReport(ExtentReports extentReports) {
        reportsThreadLocal.set(extentReports);
    }

    static ExtentReports getExtentReport() {
        return reportsThreadLocal.get();
    }
}

any help please.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the reporter instance through `com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.Reporter` class. For more information, refer this: https://github.com/email2vimalraj/CucumberExtentReporter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vimalselvam/cucumber/listener/Reporter.java#L29